Is "voracious for books" correct in terms of collocation/ fixed phrase?
I know "voracious" usually precedes the noun and is used in the phrase "have a voracious appetite for ....". However, can I say "sb is voracious for books" instead of "sb is a voracious reader"? Thanks

Don't you think that Question belongs more to English Language Learning?
Since you're here yes, you could say 'sb is voracious for books' but two things:
'… is voracious for books' will always be pushing the definition. Are you confident in leading that charge?
However correct, please never use 'sb…' in place of 'subject', the more not in such a tenuous case as this.
Thanks

“Sb” is an abbreviation for “somebody,” not “subject.”

Thank, Casey, and who could care? Did you not notice, 'sb' might be an abbreviation for either, creating confusion, and in neither instance is it ever needed?

“sb” and “sthg” are extremely common in language-learning or reference contexts and I find “abbreviations should never be used since they can be ambiguous or confusing” a rather absurd position, but I suppose I can’t control what you do or don’t care about.

The OED, Oxford English Dictionary, uses "sb" for "somebody". I think the common abbreviation for subject is ... Subj. No confusion there. I think your answers dangerously veer towards sarcasm and sneering. You should want to help people not look down on their questions. That's the impression you give. If you think the question can be improved post a comment an explain why. Post Scriptum, I didn't downvote.
